# How do you iterate over an array every x spots and replace with letter?

Tags: javascript

/*Write a function called weave that accepts an input string and number. The function should return the string with every xth character replaced with an 'x'.*/

```
    function weave(word,numSkip) {
      let myString = word.split("");
      numSkip -= 1; 
      for(let i = 0; i < myString.length; i++)
      {
        numSkip += numSkip;
        myString[numSkip] = "x";
      }
      let newString = myString.join();
      console.log(newString);
    }

    weave("weave",2);
```

I keep getting an infinite loop. I believe the answer I am looking for is "wxaxe".

Comment: You're doing weird things to `numSkip`. Can explain why, what you intended them to do?

Comment: Hint: the infinite loop happens because `numSkip` becomes larger than `word.length`, and the `myString` array (what a confusing name!) will keep growing then.

Comment: @Bergie Since the array starts at 0, I was trying to normalize the length of  the number skipping. So if the number skipping is 2, then myString[1] would be the second letter or "e' in this case.

Comment: But for that you should use a different start index, not change the number of items to skip in every step.

Comment: I now realize it's easier to start at the numSkip index given rather than at the zero-index. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution, incrementing the `for loop` by the `numToSkip` parameter.

```
function weave(word, numToSkip) {
    let letters = word.split("");
    for (let i=numToSkip - 1; i < letters.length; i = i + numToSkip) {
        letters[i] = "x"
    } 
    return letters.join("");
}
```

Comment: I think something this what I was trying to come close too. I didn't think to start the letter replacement at the numToSkip given to the weave function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to test each loop to check if it's a skip or not. Something as simple as the following will do:

```
function weave(word,numSkip) {
    var arr = word.split("");

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if((i+1) % numSkip == 0) {
            arr[i] = "x";
        }
    }

    return arr.join("");
}
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/np8e3sL7/)

---

Alternatively, you could use the `map` function:

```
function weave(word, numSkip) {
  var arr = word.split("");

  arr = arr.map(function(letter, index) {
    return (index + 1) % numSkip ? letter : 'x';
  });

  return arr.join("");
}
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/q0gaboro/)

---

Here is a more re-usable function that allows specifying the character used for substitution:

```
function weave(input, skip, substitute) {
  return input.split("").map(function(letter, index) {
    return (index + 1) % skip ? letter : substitute;
  }).join("");
}
```

Called like:

```
var result = weave('weave', 2, 'x');
```

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/oLaymx95/)

Comment: `word` is a string, not an array with assignable indices.

Comment: @Bergi: Yeah sorry, should have tested first, I have resolved the issue now

Answer (score 1):

You dont need an array, string concatenation will do it, as well as the modulo operator:

```
function weave(str,x){
 var result = "";
 for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  result += (i && (i+1)%x === 0)?"x":str[i];
 }
 return result;
}
```

With arrays:

```
const weave = (str,x) => str.split("").map((c,i)=>(i&&!((i+1)%x))?"x":c).join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting your word greater in your loop every time, so your loop is infinite.
Try something like this :

```
for(let k = 1; k <= myString.length; k++)
  {
    if(k % numSkip == 0){
         myString[k-1]='x';
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, you need a new string for the result and concat the actual character or the replacement.

```js
function weave(word, numSkip) {
    var i, result = '';

    for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        result += (i + 1) % numSkip ? word[i] : 'x';
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(weave("weave", 2));
console.log(weave("abcd efgh ijkl m", 5));
```

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely a way I didn't think about.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what you have, I believe the reason you are getting an error is because the way you update `numSkip`, it eventually becomes larger than 
`myString.length`. In my code snippet, I make i increment by `numSkip` which prevents the loop from ever executing when i is greater than `myString.length`. Please feel free to ask questions, and I will do my best to clarify!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmvuzayz/4/) of my solution (view the developer console to see the output.

```
   function weave(word,numSkip) {
      let myString = word.split("");
      for(let i = numSkip - 1; i < myString.length; i += numSkip)
      {
        myString[i] = "x";
      }
      let newString = myString.join();
      console.log(newString);
    }

    weave("weave",2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with fewer lines of code:

```js
function weave(word, numSkip) {
  word = word.split("");
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    word[i] = ((i + 1) % numSkip == 0) ? "x" : word[i];
  }
  return word.join("");
}

var result = weave("weave", 2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can do this with even fewer lines of code. Or more efficiently. See the other answers.